# Understanding figures in the algorithm design manual

Tags: algorithm

I want to start learning about algorithms so I began reading The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena because it is recommended in some threads I read in SO. However, I just stopped [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK/NODE8.HTM)
and can't understand most of it because many explanations are represented in figures or images and my screen reader recognize but can't read them.
For example,

"The nearest neighbor rule is very efficient, for it looks at each pair of points

tex2html_wrap_inline23349 //That's how my screen reader read it, I asume it's an image.

at most twice, once when adding

tex2html_wrap_inline23351 //image

to the tour, the other when adding

tex2html_wrap_inline23353 //another image

Against all these positives there is only one problem. This algorithm is completely wrong."

This is really frustrating for me because I'm beginning to enjoy this though I can understand why those images help a lot of readers.
So is their a way to understand this thing without seeing the figures? Or should I read another book?
Thanks in advance and happy new year everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering these algorithms are dealing with geometrical analysis, I am afraid it would be difficult to understand them without the images, and even more difficult to replace these images with an equivalent textual description.

Comment: Ok. So I really have to see them to learn algorithms? Are most algorithms like this?

Comment: Not at all. A lot of algorithms can be described by text only.For instance, you could tackle the theory of computer languages. Also, it depends heavily on the author's way of thinking. Some persons are more inclined to think in terms of images while others rely on verbal/textual representations. I'm sure you will find some authors who suit your needs.

Comment: And that's the problem. It seems I can't find any.

Comment: Have you considered the video lectures like this [introduction to computer science](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX3jvD7XFPs) from the MIT?